# React setState in onClick method not updating the DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor-react

I'm developing a simple game fight animation using react. To start the fight, I've a button with `onClick` event: `onClick={this.fight.bind(this)}`. Now I want to update some state variable in the anytime something changes like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ProgressBar, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
const playerA = {
    _id: 1,
    name: "playerA name",
    life: 100,
    speed: 50,
}
const playerB = {
    _id: 1,
    name: "playerB name",
    life: 100,
    speed: 40,
}

export default class App extends Compornent {

  constructor() {
    super();
      this.state={
        playerA : playerA ,
        playerB : playerB ,
        aLife: 100,
        bLife: 100,
    };
    this.fight = this.fight.bind(this);
  };

  fight(a,b){
    lifeA=this.state.playerA.live;
    lifeB=this.state.playerB.live;
    speedA=this.state.playerA.speed;
    speedB=this.state.playerB.speed;
    dmg = 10
    while (lifeA>0 && lifeB>0) {
      if (speedA > speedb) {
        lifeA = lifeA - dmg;
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.setState({ aLife: lifeA });
        }, 1000);
        speedB = speedB + 10;
      } else {
        lifeB = lifeB - dmg;
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.setState({ bLife: lifeA });
        }, 1000);
        speedA = speedA + 10;
      }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Row>
        <ProgressBar bsStyle="success" now={this.state.aLife} srOnly/>
        <ProgressBar bsStyle="success" now={this.state.bLife} srOnly/>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Button bsStyle="danger" bsSize="large" onClick={this.fight.bind(this)}>Start Fight</Button>
      </Row>
    );
  }   
}
```

My expectation is to see the progress bars beeing update every 1 second. But it only updates once. When the fight funtion has finisched beein executed.

Comment: what you trying to return on fight function?

Comment: just updated was an error. Just want that function to be executed and update the state

Answer (score 0):

refer to the ReactJs [official documents](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html), you don't have to bind this again in the render function, since you have already done the binding in Constructor Function

```
<Button bsStyle="danger" bsSize="large" onClick={this.fight.bind(this)}>Start Fight</Button>
```

should be

```
 <Button bsStyle="danger" bsSize="large" onClick={this.fight}>Start Fight</Button>
```

Comment: Its not a issue with binding as the other person is able to update state but it happens only once

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri exactly. You got it. I also tried this out with the same result. I spent already 4 days trying to figure out what was the problem. My conclusion was: I may be missing some react fundamentals(which leads me to make this post) Or there is something wrong with react state.

Comment: @danyhiol I suppose it sbecause of the timeout inside of the while loop, you loop gets executed without waiting for the timeout to change the state, I would say make use of setInterval to perform this action instead of while loop and clear the interval when either lifeA < 0 || lifeB < 0.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri would you mind providing some sample code? Because according to what you are saying, pausing the while loop should do it. But I already did that although I was not using setInterval.

Answer (score 0):

I finally get this done by completely rewriting the while loop using `setInterval` whith a bool condition: `((npcPlayerLife > 0) && (advPlayerLife > 0))` and then stop when the condition in no more meet. 
I have this help someone.